# MVVM synchronizing properties between viewmodels

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, .net-4.8

**Imagine this situation:**
There are viewmodels ViewModelA and ViewModelB. Both models are a datasource (source of truth) for a value, we can call it as "selected". There is a "Selected" property on both viewmodels. The "Selected property" is notifiable property (it invokes OnPropertyChanged event). When the ViewModelA updates the "selected" value then the ViewModelB is notified about this change and vice versa.

**My current solution:**
Both viewmodels share their references with eachother (ViewModelA have a reference to ViewModelB an vice versa). When the Selected property is set with a new value (OnPropertyChanged is ivoked) then this property is set also one the otherside.

**The catch:**
It's obvious what's wrong with my current solution: It creates infinite loop cycle of setting properties (ViewModelA sets value -> ViewModelA notifies ViewModelB -> ViewModelB sets value -> ViewModelB notifies ViewModelA -> ViewModelA sets vallue -> ...). My solution only works because when the originator of the change is notified about the change (that it made originally) the SetProperty method doesn't invoke OnPropertyChanged because the values are the same. But there is a risk of an infinitive loop in case the comparison of an old and the new one evaluates (from some reason) incorrectly.

**Question:** How to safely sync values between two viewmodels?

Comment: You could possibly have yet another model, call it the mediator, that has one-way references to the two. And synchronizes to the two. The mediator would be the source of truth for this specific property.

Comment: _"How to safely sync values between two viewmodels?"_ - By enforcing a strict one-way-flow of data and state updates through your application - that guiding principle is the basis of Redux and ReactJS and is why they're so popular today (despite the steep learning-curve for grokking _reducers_ and _functors_). I strongly recommend you try it: https://www.google.com/search?q=redux+for+wpf

Comment: Store the state in only one object, e.g. a third view model that is held in properties of ViewModelA and ViewModelB.

Comment: You should encapsulate this property in 3ed component (service or view model ...etc.) and this component is the only responsible to change it. Both view models A and B should have a dependency on this 3ed component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If two classes depend on the same data, then this data must be encapsulated.
You don't want to maintain multiple instances of a data object to reflect the same state.
You don't want to create a cyclic class dependency so that the dependencies observe and update each other.
Instead, we would share data.

The most common way is to use composition. In your case, you would introduce a parent view model (e.g. `MainViewModel`) that is composed of the types that depend on the shared data (`ViewModelA` and `ViewModelB`). This parent view model class also controls the lifetime of the shared instance. For example, it would be responsible to dispose or recreate/replace the instance if necessary.

Another solution could be to make use of the Dependency Injection design pattern to create shared instances. In this scenario the IoC container would manage the lifetime of the shared instance.

**SharedDataModel.cs**
The shared data object.

```cs
class SharedDataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // TODO::Raise PropertyChanged
  public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**
The parent class that shares the data with its composition children.

```cs
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // The view will bind to the view model classes via the MainViewModel
  public ViewModelA ViewModelA { get; }
  public ViewModelB ViewModelB { get; }

  private SharedDataModel SharedData { get; }

  public MainViewModel()
  {
    this.SharedData = new SharedDataModel();
    this.ViewModelA = new ViewModelA(this.SharedDataModel);
    this.ViewModelB = new ViewModelB(this.SharedDataModel);
  }
}
```

**ViewModelA.cs**
Consumer of the shared data. The shared object is not directly exposed. Instead, the data is exposed via delegation.

```cs
class ViewModelA : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private SharedDataModel SharedData { get; }

  private string someData;
  public string SomeData 
  {
    get => this.SharedData;
    set
    {
      // Because SharedData is a reference type, 
      // modifying the instance in one context 
      // will also modify the instance in every other context 
      // that references the same instance (shared instance).
      //
      // Therefore, ViewModelB will also see the current changes 
      // made to the SharedDataModel instance.
      //
      // Delegate the new value to the shared SharedDataModel instance:
      this.SharedData.SomeData = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }
  
  public ViewModelA(SharedDataModel sharedData)
    => this.SharedData = sharedData;
}
```

**ViewModelB.cs**
Consumer of the shared data. The shared object is not directly exposed. Instead, the data is exposed via delegation.

```cs
class ViewModelB : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private SharedDataModel SharedData { get; }

  private string someData;
  public string SomeData 
  {
    get => this.SharedData;
    set
    {
      // Because SharedData is a reference type, 
      // modifying the instance in one context 
      // will also modify the instance in every other context 
      // that references the same instance (shared instance).
      //
      // Therefore, ViewModelA will also see the current changes 
      // made to the SharedDataModel instance.
      //
      // Delegate the new value to the shared SharedDataModel instance:
      this.SharedData.SomeData = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }
  
  public ViewModelB(SharedDataModel sharedData)
    => this.SharedData = sharedData;
}
```

**Usage example**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MainViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ViewModelA.SomeData}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ViewModelB.SomeData}" /> 
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

If you don't mind to expose the complete `SharedDataModel` instance,
you can omit the delegation (as suggested by Clemens in the comments):

**ViewModelA.cs**
Consumer of the shared data. In this example the shared object is directly exposed. This solution would violate the Information Hiding principle if the view is not supposed to access the complete `SharedDataModel` API.

```cs
class ViewModelA : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // TODO::Raise PropertyChanged
  //
  // Because SharedData is a reference type, 
  // modifying the instance in one context 
  // will also modify the instance in every other context 
  // that references the same instance (shared instance).
  //
  // Therefore, ViewModelA will also see the current changes 
  // made to the SharedDataModel instance.
  public SharedDataModel SharedData { get; }
  
  public ViewModelA(SharedDataModel sharedData)
    => this.SharedData = sharedData;
}
```

**ViewModelB.cs**
Consumer of the shared data. In this example the shared object is directly exposed. This solution would violate the Information Hiding principle if the view is not supposed to access the complete `SharedDataModel` API.

```cs
class ViewModelB : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // TODO::Raise PropertyChanged
  //
  // Because SharedData is a reference type, 
  // modifying the instance in one context 
  // will also modify the instance in every other context 
  // that references the same instance (shared instance).
  //
  // Therefore, ViewModelA will also see the current changes 
  // made to the SharedDataModel instance.
  public SharedDataModel SharedData { get; }
  
  public ViewModelB(SharedDataModel sharedData)
    => this.SharedData = sharedData;
}
```

**Usage example**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MainViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ViewModelA.SharedData.SomeData}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ViewModelB.SharedData.SomeData}" /> 
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: You can as well make `ViewModelA/B.SharedData` public, drop `ViewModelA/B.SomeData` and write `{Binding SharedData.SomeData}`. Private properties should be fields.

Comment: Yes, exposing the `SharedData` property directly is another solution. Thanks for pointing that out. But it depends on the desired visibility of the shared data. Exposing the shared data directly means that any class can reference it which is not always desired. We usually want to control the access. But it really depends on the data and use case.

Comment: @Clemens I have included your suggestion in the answer. Thanks for the improvement.

Comment: May I also suggest to make the SharedData properties read-only?

Comment: Of course, you are welcome. What's the point of sharing the instance when the contract can be broken so easily. I should have been more careful - this usually doesn't happen. Thanks again!

Comment: If you're on .NET 8, you can also use a primary constructor like `class ViewModelA(SharedData sharedData) { public SharedDataModel SharedData => sharedData; }`. Left out the INPC stuff.

Comment: That's a nice feature, I agree. I'm always reluctant to post code using the latest language features especially in context of rather trivial problems. From experience, this confuses a lot of people. Most use an older .NET version and will struggle to fix compiler errors when they use features that are not supported by their current runtime. Then I have to come back and post the old style. On the other hand, it's also good to promote new language features.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution of comparing values should work, as long as there are no inexact computations of values involved. Another possibility is to use a `bool isUpdating` to prevent loops. But my preferred solution it to use a separate object that is shared between both view models.

Something like:

```
public class MyProp<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private T value;

    public T Value
    {
        get => value;
        set => SetField(ref this.value, value);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```